# Error installing google sdk permission denied in folder google-cloud-sdk.staging\test.mp3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk

```
Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.staging\platform\gsutil\gslib\tests\test_data\test.mp3

Ensure you have the permissions to access the file and that the file is not in use.
```

i ran in admin mode but still got this error. how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi, could you please share the command you are running?

Comment: Im using windows there are no commands as i am running the sdk setup file in admin mode

Comment: Could you try to open a PowerShell and run the [following commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#windows)?      
                         `(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe", "$env:Temp\GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe")

& $env:Temp\GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe`